# how to control page loading workflow

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>
<div class="hidden">
<img src="...">
<img src="...">
<img src="...">
</div>

<img src="...">
</body>
```

Because `.hidden` div is not displayed, how can I check does the browser firstly loads all its children images, or maybe jumps outside the hidden div, in order to loading visible images firstly ?

If not, is there a way to write such an instruction, using javascript, or somehow else.

I'm using Chrome, updated.

Comment: The browser loads resources (`script`s,`img`s) in the order it finds it in the markup.

Comment: @wumm, does that mean that if a `hidden` images is `2MB` and the next, visible image is `2KB` I must wait to load `2MB` firstly? Is there a way to change this ?

Comment: Most browsers *start* loading the images in the order they find them. But they are not waiting until the load of the first picture finished but they start the load of the next one. So basically  you can say browsers load all images at the same time, because you can't really see that progress of parsing the HTML.

Comment: Another two ways: a) Move the `<div class="hidden">` to the bottom of the page. If you need this div rendered before the images, you can do that with CSS. b) Remove the `<div class="hidden">` from the page, and add it dynamically with JS when page is loaded.

Comment: I usually use a tiny 1x1 blank image as the `src` attribute and specify the actual source inside a `data-` attribute - And then load the images via JS once the DOM is ready (or whenever you need them to be loaded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onload` handlers for each image to monitor when they get loaded:

```
<body onload="console.log('body.onload')">
<div class="hidden">
<img src="..." onload="console.log('Loaded: ' + this.src)">
<img src="..." onload="console.log('Loaded: ' + this.src)">
<img src="..." onload="console.log('Loaded: ' + this.src)">
</div>
<img src="..." onload="console.log('Loaded: ' + this.src)">
</body>
```

Comment: `onload` shows the time when an image is `started` loading or `finished` loading ?

Comment: `onload` usually means when a resource finished loading, i.e. is ready to use.

Comment: @bonaca - I was wondering too. I believe it was by someone who hates inline event handling. In this particular case though, that pretty much the only option we have.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted you, but how come placing `onload` event handlers prevents the first div from loading first? It just lets you know when the elements are loaded, not setting their loading sequence.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos - Yes, but the OP will be able to see the important point that they'll be loaded even though their parent isn't visible.